# wordpress takes off any html added to post in editor

Tags: wordpress

I am using WordPress 3.4. with only the plugins that come with the wordpress default installation.

My problem is that I cannot add any links or html to my posts from the editor.

It seems that wordpress is filtering all code off and I can only add text.

I've also tried to embed code via the html tab but again the code just gets wiped out.

Any ideas of why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Adding HTML code in the HTML text-area should be fine alright, but it will strip some codes if it's not written in valid HTML. Can you paste the code you've been trying to add?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am correct in thinking that you mean switching between the visual and HTML editors. I ran into this as well, a few weeks ago, and after researching for over an hour it seems that this is just how the editor works.

Searching Google for " html stripped wordpress editor " will bring up results for this, going back to 2008.

My research led to me installing **Preserved HTML Editor Markup** and **TinyMCE Advanced**, to ensure that no html/code is stripped when saving a draft, or switching editor modes.

After installing the plugins, you will have to make one setting change for TinyMCE Advanced. In the admin area, navigate to 'Settings > TinyMCE Advanced'. Under Advanced Settings, [check this setting.](http://i46.tinypic.com/6gzam1.png)

Your HTML code should no longer be stripped when switching between the editors or saving a draft. If this isn't what you were referring to, sorry!

Plugins:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/preserved-html-editor-markup
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced

(I would have used hyperlinks but I need 10 reputation to use more than two hyperlinks in a post.)